# How do I bind the value of a dependency property in the UserControl it's defined in XAML?

Tags: wpf

Suppose I have a UserControl which has a DataContext set to it's VM

Now suppose the UserControl has a dependency property defined that I want to initially bind to a property on the ViewModel ...how would I reference this property in the XAML of the UserControl given the top-level element is UserControl?

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestApp1.TestControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp1"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" x:Name="test">

</UserControl>
```

Dependency property:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTestPropProperty= null;

    public string MyTestProp
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyTestPropProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyTestPropProperty, value); }
    }

    static TestControl()
    {
        MyTestPropProperty= DependencyProperty.Register(
            "MyTestProp",
            typeof(string), 
            typeof(TestControl), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());
    }
```

On the XAML I"d like to be able go MyTestProp={Binding yadda yadda} but I have no way to reference it from XAML

Answer (score 0):

Just add the property in the root node like so:

`<Usercontrol xmlns=blablabla
              MyProperty="{Binding MyViewModelProperty}">`

Edit: This doesn't work because there is no XAML reference to the newly created property. Either use a `<Style TargetType="TestControl">` or set the property from an outer context (the one that contains this usercontrol)

Comment: I can't because "MyProperty" isn't recognized by the designer since the root item is technically UserControl and "MyProperty" is defined in my UserControl-derived code-behind class

Comment: OMG why are you using the designer? just write it manually in XAML. also, in order for this to work your property must be a DependencyProperty, not a regular clr property. regular properties are not bindable

Comment: Sorry, not the designer the XAML editor (I use the two terms interchangeably my bad), and this property I've defined IS a dependency property but the problem is in the XAML editor the UserControl is the top-level element. My UserControl is a derived class, therefore that property is not in scope of the XAML editor

Comment: I don't think it works that way... have you defined the x:Class attribute in the root node? post your code so I can understand better

Comment: There's something I don't get.. your XAML defines the class name as TestApp1.TestControl, but then you have a `static FilterControl()` ctor... whats the correct name?

Comment: TestControl - sorry I was trying to remove all the extraneous stuff